# Problemas de conexion con sql server 2017

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el servidor o éste no estaba accesible.
>   Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir conexiones remotas. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - No se pudo abrir una conexión con SQL Server)'

Este es mi codigo donde me marca error:

```
private void CargarUsuarios()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT NOMBRE from SERV.USUARIOS", conn);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    ddwUsuario.DataSource = ds;
    ddwUsuario.DataTextField = "NOMBRE";
    ddwUsuario.DataValueField = "NOMBRE";
    ddwUsuario.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: este es mi codigo donde me marca error.                                                
private void CargarUsuarios()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT NOMBRE from SERV.USUARIOS", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            ddwUsuario.DataSource = ds; ddwUsuario.DataTextField = "NOMBRE";
ddwUsuario.DataValueField = "NOMBRE";
ddwUsuario.DataBind();
}

Comment: no tienes bien la cadena de conexion muy probablemente

Comment: esta es mi conexion SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-MBRCH91;Initial Catalog=SERVINEXT;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;

Comment: Y en el web.config tengo esta otra conexion                                                                  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connServinext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-MBRCH91;Initial Catalog=SERVINEXT; Integrated security=true;" />
  </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 0):

si tienes una conexion en el web.config debes poner en tu clase este metodo

```
SqlConnection cnn= new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connServinext"].ToString());
```